# Why has my pyautogui Code stopped locating buttons on the screen?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, pyautogui

My program was working fine, locating the area the button was in using `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` and then locating the center of the button using `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen` obviously with a file path to the correct image.

Now, though, running it returns the value of none for both the center and location.

I have uninstalled pyautogui and reinstalled it and it has not fixed it.

I am only focusing on the RecordMP3 bit of code

Here is my code

```
import pyautogui, time
def RecordMP3():
    time.sleep(5)
    RecordMP3 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("D:/Programming/Python/AutoGUI/Images/SaveButton.PNG")
    print(RecordMP3)
    CenterRecordMP3 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("D:/Programming/Python/AutoGUI/Images/SaveButton.PNG",region = (RecordMP3))
    print(CenterRecordMP3)  
    pyautogui.click(CenterRecordMP3)

def SaveButton():
    while True:
        counter = 0
        SaveButton = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("D:/Programming/Python/AutoGUI/Images/SaveButton.PNG")
        print("Location",SaveButton)
        SaveButtonCenter = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("D:/Programming/Python/AutoGUI/Images/SaveButton.PNG", region = (SaveButton))
        print("Center",SaveButtonCenter,)
        pyautogui.click(SaveButtonCenter)
        time.sleep=(2)
        counter +=1
        if counter < 10:
            continue
        else:
            break

#print("it worked!!")  
RecordMP3()
```

This is the screen I search:

[image: Screen I want to search for button]

And this is the button I'm trying to find:

[image: The record button I want to find]

Comment: When program behavior changes, it's very helpful to note things you have done which could have influenced that change in behavior. Here you simply state `"it worked before, now it doesn't"`, which is not useful at all. Did you update software versions? Did the website layout change? Did you change file paths? Providing information that indicates *what has changed* is necessary for proper debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Though my suggestion is also a little late I have run into this issue as well like many other people.

I have solved this by compyling the .py into .exe with auto-py-to-exe.

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Though my suggestion is a little late I have run into this issue as well. I have solved this by taking another screen shot of the image I am looking for. As a friendly reminder if the image is not pixel perfect pyautogui wont find it.

Hope you found a solution!